# What does a fitted curve for the period of a variable star, tell me about the star?

Tags: data-analysis, light-curve, variable-star, cepheids, dwarf-star

If I have enough data of a variable star to make a light curve for it's whole period, and If I  fit a function to that light curve, can that fitted function tell me anything about the properties of the star?

If so, is it different for different types of stars?

Comment: It can tell you a lot.  This intro video on light curve analysis will probably be of some help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQrGrEu98wc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it can tell you **a lot** of stuff. You could identify (probably) the following:

- Type of star E.g. a light curve of a eclipsing binary system

[image]

Light curve of supernova:

[image]

Not only that you can also identify the **radius** (thereafter volume), **size** of the planet, and the orbital period by measuring the elapsed time between transits.

You can identify quite a bit of information. Given you find orbital period, radius etc., you can use this information to find other information too. So it keeps branching!

[Note](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/310/orbits-and-keplers-laws/):

> Kepler's Third Law: the squares of the orbital periods of the planets are directly proportional to the cubes of the semi-major axes of their orbits. Kepler's Third Law implies that the period for a planet to orbit the Sun increases rapidly with the radius of its orbit.

References:

- https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/toolbox/timing1.html